# SWF with multiple "stages"

Tags: html, flash, flash-cs5

Is it possible to have a single SWF file with multiple "stages" appearing at different parts of the page and sharing data? 
What I'm trying to do requires sharing big amount of data (byteArrays of image data) that cannot be shared through LocalConnections or via JS (very slow) so I'm trying to avoid the "sharing" part and somehow do it in a single SWF. Problem is, those images need to appear on different parts of the page thus I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one Stage in swfs - the Stage is effectively the background; and you cant have more than one background.

"Problem is, those images need to appear on different parts of the page" - why cant you adjust the position of the images?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. See what I'm trying to do is loading images with flash selected by the user from his HDD (with FileReference) which then after resized to thumbnail size need to be placed at different parts of the page along with some HTML stuff. I tried opening the images and sending them to JS after PNG encoding them and Base64 (to use with Data URIs) but this is incredibly slow.
So I thought maybe there is some way to avoid the encoding->JS step and instead have small SWFs dynamically created, getting passed the loaded img from the main swf, and placed on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use swf 100x100 % of browser window with transparent bg (wmode='transparent'), load images and place them in appropriate position. Main problem how to calculte coordinates for thumbnails...  ^)

And flash with transparent bg very slow too...

Comment: Yes unfortunately calculating the coordinates would be hard and speed is an issue too. Nice idea though :)

Comment: I think the best way is to get images into flash (one instance), resize it in memory and upload to server as tmb, and then download with JS as regular images...

Comment: Yes this is what I was avoiding to do (wanted it all client side) but it seems I'm going to do something like this :)